# use string in <title> to change string in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery script to change strings to something else based on the divs initial string as well as adding an extra class to the element. Works great.

However, I just got in a situation that I need to be able to target a few  divs based in a string in the sites title tags when a special users logg in thus the title change.

Is this possible? Both Vanilla JS and jQuery is good for me.

Script I am using:

```
 $( "span.conditionHilite:contains('Standard')" )
  .text('Approved Selection').addClass( "approvedSelectionHilite" );
```

I would like to run that script *ONLY* if the title contains a certain string.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a little more. How does the snippet of code you've posted relate to the `title`? What value are you trying to get from `title`, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Hi Rory. I want to run the script only if the <title> tags contains a specific  string. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Ok, but what is that string? And where does it come from

Comment: The string belongs to the specific customers information. Its the name of the company of that customer. When the customer logs in this adds to the <title> tags. I want to use my script when this strings is meet in the title tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code

```
if($('title:contains("Your specific string")')){
// do your task 
$( "span.conditionHilite:contains('Standard')" )
  .text('Approved Selection').addClass( "approvedSelectionHilite" );

}
```

Comment: Actually.. It changes the strings even if title doesnt contains the specific string. So close! @AdarshGowdaKR

Answer (score 0):

*I just got in a situation that I need to be able to target a few divs based in a string in the sites title tags.*

you can cache it before like this:

```
var title = document.title.trim(); // <---gives you the title of the document.
$( "div:contains("+title+")").css('border', 'solid red 1px');
```

---

When you use the code snippet above you can see what is it doing:

1. caching the document title in a `var title` as posted.
2. When you cache it you can use this `var title` in the code with concatenation.
3. Just for a demo purpose i have attached the css method of jquery.

Comment: Hi Jai. Not sure how this would work? I would want to run the script that changes the divs string only when the <title> tag contains a specific string? @Jai

Answer (score 0):

You should use the the syntax 
    $( "[attribute='value']" )
Here the doc 
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

For example you could change the text of all the divs having title=Standard

```
$("div[title='Standard']).each(function(index,value){    
    $(this).text("change-me")
});
```

Comment: I am succesfully changing the text in the divs with the script I posted - Im looking to run the script only when the <title> tags have a certain string in them.

Comment: var title = $("title:contains('demo')");  

      
// you may want to retrieve the full text of the title


var value =  title.text();    
    
if(title){
        //your code here
    }